# Need Help to stop refrshing on the J query effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I'm currently working on a school project and I"m currently working on a J query 
Simple Slide show.The codes seems to work fine.

However I realize that after each picture being shown, the page automatically refreshes on its own in which i find it rather irritating as i have some text below the slideshow and before i can finish reading the text the page ended up refreshing.

I seek great advice on this issue thanks A lot.

Comment: Attached? What? where? and please Add some code. Edit the question to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `anchor tags` for `slideshow` so use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) on `click event` to prevent page `refresh/reload` like,

```
$("a.className").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code for slideshow
});
```

Comment: or he could remove the `href="#"` which is a pretty makeshift way of doing it but it works. or not use anchor tags at all, buttons are made for that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **JQuery ajax** to get a ***json response*** to stop page refreshing on each pic change...